# On average, how often do users redeem themselves from a post ban of either kind?

Tags: discussion, post-ban, statistics

This is something that I've been curious about for a bit, since I don't have any anecdotal evidence to go off of, and maybe one or two cases that come to mind of this happening.  But, what are the rough statistics on a user that is question or answer banned, and how often do those same users reverse that ban?

I've always held that it's a vanishingly small number - somewhere on the order of 3% - but if possible, I'd like to see some numbers - at least a ballpark.

Some slices that would be curious to look at:

- By reputation (north of 200 and up to 5000, if the numbers don't seem to fade into obscurity)
- If users have been warned, but haven't adjusted to the warnings

Comment: You might also want to know how often users which are *warned* about *being in dange of getting post-banned* improve.

Comment: Some old data: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172300/what-happens-to-folks-who-get-question-banned-by-and-large

Comment: @Deduplicator:  That's not a bad thing either, although I would suspect that, depending on the volume of questions alone (and judging by the sheer number of questions on the site), that the likelihood of a user improving their questions based on getting the warning is probably 1 in 4.  Worth knowing, though.

Comment: This should maybe be part of the bigger "year in review" http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272040/should-we-create-a-year-in-review/

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I'm not gonna break this down by rep, that's entirely too tedious. But here are some other stats...

### In the past 30 days...

- **460** users have hit the answer block at least once. **39** have gone on to post at least one answer afterwards.
- **4,448** users have hit the question block at least once. **95** have gone on to post at least one question afterwards.
- **4,302** users have hit the question [*quality rate-limiter*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking-rate-limited) at least once, and **1,098** have gone on to ask at least one more question.

#### Context

During this time period, **286,638** answers have been posted by **88,442** users.

During this time period, **242,919** questions have been posted by **144,509** users.

If we assume that no blocked user would ever post more than one answer a day, then the answer blocks and rate-limits have prevented **605** answers from being posted during this period.

If we assume that no blocked user would ever post more than one question a day, then the question blocks and rate-limits have prevented **7,522** questions from being asked during this period.

### In the past 365 days...

- **4,151** users have hit the answer block at least once. **781** have gone on to post at least one more answer, and **63** have then gotten themselves answer-blocked *again*.
- **24,994** users have hit the question block at least once. **3,319** have gone on to post at least one more question, and **1,304** have then gotten themselves question-blocked *again*.
- **41,873** users have hit the question quality rate-limiter at least once, **23,690** of whom have gone on to ask at least one more question, out of whom **10,145** have gotten rate-limited *again*, and **3,266** who've gone on to get fully question-blocked.

#### Warnings in the past 365 days...

- **6,769** users have been warned about their answer quality at least once, **649** went on to actually get answer-blocked.
- **95,623** users have been warned about their question quality at least once, **25,067** went on to get question-blocked OR rate-limited.

#### Context

During this time period, **3,702,862** answers have been posted by **593,358** users.

During this time period, **3,105,000** questions have been posted by **961,474** users.

If we assume that no blocked user would ever post more than one answer a day, then the answer blocks and rate-limits have prevented **7,300** answers from being posted during this period.

If we assume that no blocked user would ever post more than one question a day, then the question blocks and rate-limits have prevented **91,501** questions from being asked during this period. Hey, that's pretty close to 3%...

Comment: These are the kind of statistics that destroyed the MSDN Forums.  Cooked numbers that made everybody feel good and hid all signals that there were very serious problems.  At least replace "users" with "accounts" and you can still make it look good without having to deal with the problem.

Comment: @HansPassant: I'm a little curious: What sort of *uncooked* numbers would you be looking for, and how would I or someone else tell if we'd gotten those instead?

Comment: Is there any accounting of users who work around the ban by spinning up a new account?  I think perhaps the point @HansPassant is making is that you can't necessarily equate an inactive account with a prevented question/answer, unless you can be certain that the user didn't simply abandon the blocked account and create a new one.  Typical Internet problem.

Comment: I'm sorry, @Hans - did you think these numbers were at all *impressive?* I did include context, after all... I'd hoped you could see from it that they're actually pitifully low. I'm not gonna play semantics or try to suss out cheaters in a population that is *at best* 10% of the total, even including the newer rate-limiting system. For all the whining here, the sad truth of the q-ban system is that it barely affects anyone.

Comment: To the extent that we can identify users who do this, @aroth, we stop them from using their new accounts, or hobble their activity in some way. The big fat unknown here though is folks who just create a new account for *every question*. They never get banned, never get warned... They do get rate-limited, but not *nearly* as strictly as they should be. We put a lot of work into improving this over the past year or so, but it's been hard to eke out more than incremental gains.

Comment: @shog9 I can only hope this work you speak of does not involve designing some kind of AI, because it can only end up with it deciding to nuke humanity to be done with it :)

Comment: With regard to "hit the block at least once and went on to post at least once afterwards", is there a distinction made or recorded between never _trying_ to post again vs. getting blocked and attempting but failing to work out of it?

Comment: I'm curious about the fraction of users that made **good** posts after a block expired.  (i.e. upvoted / accepted answers and questions.)

Comment: That's not nearly enough bans handed out.  Should be harsher. First question is down voted and closed? You are banned.