# Add a badge for recovering from a post ban

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, post-ban, badge-request

Everyone knows that getting out of a question ban or answer ban is hard. We should reward those brave souls who do so with a badge for their accomplishment.

Ideas for naming the badge: "rehab", "recovery", "ex-con", "triumph", "much improved", "posting again".

Comment: How likely is it that such a badge would motivate completionists to get a question ban so they could then "recover" from it to get this badge?

Comment: Well, I've never gotten a question ban. What's my reward?

Comment: It's worth noting that a *very* large portion of people that go above the threshold end up going back.  This is partly due to the fact that there are so many factors that the post ban considers, that even if there's a general downward trend, it's not linear, there's often some wobbling right around the threshold that results in a lot of people going in and out of the ban over time.  Additionally, lots of people that are banned that get out of it end up posting more bad content eventually and getting banned again.  Shog shared some stats a while back, but I don't remember where to find them.

Comment: @Mike that you never have had to go through the arduous process of recovering. It's like asking why non-alcoholics aren't given AA sobriety rewards.

Comment: There's bound to be a few who will deliberately get into a post ban just to get the badge to get out of it.

Comment: This could very well motivate people to get question bans, which is something we absolutely don't want.

Comment: No, it's like asking why people who have never gotten convicted of a crime don't get "you got out of jail" parties. Many alcoholics don't have a choice over their disease, but people have a choice over whether they get a question ban.

Comment: @servy lots of people go "in and out" of rehab. We could have a "Lindsay Lohan" badge for those who repeatedly "recover", or we could award a "Mark Twain" (who boasted that quitting smoking was so easy that he had done it a thousand times).

Comment: @RobertColumbia So why do we want to encourage these behaviors instead of encouraging people to be *positive* contributors to the community.

Comment: @servy the point could be to encourage people to improve their posts rather than create a new account.

Comment: @RobertColumbia So you think that if we created this badge people would suddenly turn from unproductive users of the site into productive users just because of this one badge?  That's all that's standing between them and being a positive contributor to the site?  I...don't believe you.  If incentive systems like badges (or reputation) actually mattered to the type of person who gets question banned, they wouldn't have gotten question banned, because they'd *already* be providing lots of valuable contributions to get all of the other badges out there.

Comment: @Servy: [You *may* be looking for this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/313637/1079354), although this data's over two years old now.

Comment: I don't think most users will want a badge like that basically announcing that they used to make low-quality posts. I get wanting to acknowledge someone accomplishing something difficult but I think this may have the opposite effect.

Comment: @Makoto That looks like what I was thinking of, yeah.

Comment: Apart from Jon’s arguments below, you are making the wrong assumption that people would want their past question ban to be publicly known. We get lots of “please delete this old post of mine, I didn’t know better then” requests. In general, people are not keen to show of evidence that they were once failing at asking good questions.

Comment: Note that question bans are not public. Only moderators can see if an account is currently banned. The same goes for review bans, suggested edit bans, chat bans. Only active account suspensions are publicly visible, and then only while active, the public can’t see a history of account suspensions. We are not going to change this policy by branding accounts with a badge.

Comment: This comes pretty close to being a [demerit badge](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/12/16/badges-positive-only/).

Answer (score 27):

People aren't question banned immediately from a single bad post (well they can be technically - but that's neither here or there for this answer).

You're still given opportunities to post again - but you're warned when you click the ask question button that your previous posts haven't been well received and instructions on how you should go about improving them before you want to post the question you are now and asked to confirm doing so.

If that question isn't well received - the system will probably prevent you asking questions for a bit of time.

After that you're again free to ask - during that period you'll get a "not happening - because" with why, but after that that expires, you'll get told again to make sure you want to post that question.

If you're being told "stop digging!", been prevented from doing so for your own good, and keep insisting and dig further... I see no reason to award you for climbing out of your hole when we did everything to stop you digging it in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

A badge for recovering from a question ban, would in the long term eventually motivate people to post very bad question & answers to get a ban to recover from.

Even if this sounds stupid, I could imagine some people would do that just to get all that badges out there.

That is not the purpose of rewarding. The community should be motivated to avoid such a ban and not to provoke it. And that is what the Badges and Reputation is aiming at. These stuff rewards good questions, good answers and participating in a constructive and not a destructive way.

If we don't want to provoke a flood of bad posts, we shouldn't do that.