# How do I improve questions marked as Duplicate or Off-Topic when trying to lift a question ban?

Tags: support, post-ban

I recently got a question ban, which I'm trying to get lifted by improving my bad questions.

I have four questions that have a negative amount of votes. Two of these I have tried to improve, but the other two I don't really know what to do with. One is just straight up really bad and I have no idea how to improve it, that's why I deleted it in the first place. The other one is about the validity of a particular framework, which got marked as off-topic. I did not know that was an off-topic subject, so I deleted it since it can't be rewritten to something that is on-topic.

Since both of these questions still count towards my ban I would really like to improve on them, but I am not sure how. I also have a couple of questions that are marked as duplicate, which I would guess counts towards the ban, that I don't know how to make better.

Is there a standard way to improve these types of questions?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: It's not actually a ban but a rate limit to 1 question every six months. If you can't fix any of your questions you've got 6 months to create a really stellar question.

Comment: That's really depressing

Comment: Really, you just thought you were permanently banned and now you know you're not.

Comment: Well no, since the help center says that if you improve your questions and prove that you are a net plus for the website the ban will be lifted

Comment: And that's still an option for you.

Comment: If you have a Question that doesn't have Answers, you don't have to improve it as such. You can re-purpose the Question to an entirely different Question. Just make it a really good Question :)

Comment: @RobertLongson and that's why I'm here. I'm looking for advice on how to improve my question.

Comment: @Scratte That sounds great! Should I just edit the question or is there another way to do it?

Comment: How else can you change it than edit it? I can't see your deleted Questions, but they count on your Question ban. So if it was me, I'd use one of them. Spend a good amount of time making your Question (on your own system with your own editor). When you're ready, then undeleted and edit your Question. This way it will only be visible as "the old Question" for a minute.

Comment: Check the timeline of your Question after you've re-purposed it. See if it goes into a review queue for re-opening :) If it doesn't it'll remain closed.

Comment: @Scratte: *entirely rewriting* a question to something *entirely else* is not allowed. If this is spotted by someone with the right privileges it'll be rolled back.

Comment: @usr2564301 If it doesn't have any answers, it's not invalidating anything. If it's closed or deleted, it's already not bringing value to the site. Are you proposing deleted and closed question must remain with their original off-topic content because it would be bad to change them into something that's valuable?

Comment: You are not question banned without warning. By the way, quality content warnings were shown to you before you posted a question on four different occasions. I can see the history event "**User posted after seeing a quality ban warning**" on four dates

Answer (score 9):

I'm just going to say the quiet part out loud.

> Is there a standard way to improve these types of questions?

**No.**

There's no *standard* way to "fix" these questions, since, quite frankly, the kinds of questions you describe aren't "fixable".  No amount of editing or massaging is going to make those contributions actually materially good.

The violent and unfortunate Catch-22 you're caught in dictates that you must improve your questions to be able to ask questions at a normal clip, but there aren't any improvements available for a question asking "what framework is viable in situation X", or for a *truly* bad question.

The main reason such a gate exists at all is so users who routinely and consistently post bad content get severely rate limited - one question every 6 or so months.  However, every now and then someone who realizes the issue at hand (e.g. don't post questions which are consistently poorly received - it ain't just two of 'em!) comes along and gets bit by this.

Unfortunately, there's not much else you can do with the really, really bad questions except learn from those and **move forward**.

**Improve the way you ask questions.** Don't look to ask open-ended questions or seek "advice"; try and experiment and then come back to Stack Overflow if you're stuck on something specific.

**This is not an instantaneous improvement.**  It may take some amount of time before you're out of this heavy rate limit, but if you truly want to stay the course, you *can* escape it.  I'm not going to sugar coat it - [your chances of escaping are *slim*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/313641/1079354) considering how many times the system had warned you before it got to this point, but they at least *exist*.

Comment: Wow, that's really depressing. Especially considering I must have missed the warnings. I had no idea my questions could get me into this situation.

Comment: Questions are a finite resource as the time and energy of volunteers is heavily, heavily constrained.  I'm not exactly a fan of the harshness and I think there should be some improvements to the system overall, but I'm not interested in painting you a rosy picture when in my experience, no such picture exists.

Comment: @Grebalb - You were notified at some point, that you questions were not being well  received, this warning happened sometime before your last question was submitted.  It might have happened when you submitted your last two questions, the point is, you were notified of this fact.  You would not be the first user to have seen this notification and not asked about it.