# A dummy review queue could benefit question-banned, new users to learn how to ask good questions

Tags: discussion, new-users, post-ban

For new users who get placed in a question ban, I think that some percentage of them aren't necessarily lazy and just don't realize the damage they are doing to the site.

I myself actually was placed in a question ban, but I was able to escape by editing questions and posting answers.

One of the things that best helped me in understanding what a well asked question is grinding out the review queue badges.

I think for new users placed in a Q-ban, they could be given access to a "dummy queue" with both good and bad questions for them to practice identifying. If they choose to actually go through the process I think that is enough work to be given a 2nd chance. Maybe 1000 correct answers or something like that.

I don't think it is possible or that anyone genuinely believes you can escape the ban by editing your past questions.

Comment: There is already a lot of stuff available on how to ask (good) question and still people write bad question. I agree that some aren't necessarily lazy, but those might don't care as long as they get their question answered. I don't think that adding more stuff for users to read doesn't help anymore. There is already more than enough.

Comment: Users who are asking questions, that result in a question ban, should be staying away from reviewing questions and making the determination that other user's questions are acceptable and non-acceptable.

Comment: @SecurityHound the proposal is for those users to try classifying already classified questions. Thus the system will not do any changes to the posts.

Comment: Interesting idea, although I'd give a dummy queue for *reviewers* too given the overall "quality" of reviews...

Comment: @Oleg On that note... https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/289871/4014959

Comment: Is your question a way to say that the "ask-question" wizard is not powerful enough? What needs to be added?

Comment: @Dominique "*Is your question a way to say that the "ask-question" wizard is not powerful enough?*" that's not how I read this question. With that said, the answer is that yes, the ask wizard is indeed powerless to prevent users from getting question banned. As evidenced by the fact that users are still getting question bans even after the wizard was introduced.

Comment: @VLAZ: so we could use this question as an opportunity to gather some inspiration for modifications to the wizard :-)

Comment: @Dominique There is probably only one one modification that I can think of that will make the wizard drastically reduce the question bans. It's if we used one of those wizards with a robe, pointy hat, living in a tower, and reading arcane tomes.

Comment: The [Staging Ground](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/416428/10871073) - whose release is now on the cards - may resolve many of the issues with new users and the quality of their questions.

Comment: I mean... if the dummy review queue is anything like the audits that real review queues see...

Comment: Also related: [The Good, The Bad & The Ugly](/q/266361): "_Give new users and persistent offenders (who write poorly received posts) a tutorial they must complete before they can post, which highlights good and bad posts, along with reasoning as to why they are judged as they are._"

Comment: Truth be told, what you propose is essentially a form of spoon feeding. I don't think we're ready yet to admit that spoon feeding is what is needed in this day and age. But me personally I do think you're on to something there. A review queue though... review queues are automatically generated. This kind of educational tool should not be random, it should be handcrafted. Not going to happen.

Comment: Related to Gimby's comment on handcrafting, there is an appetite for that in the community. See [Help us identify new roles for community members - Audit moderators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/384179/997587)

Comment: A review queue that only contains audits? A terrifying concept.

Comment: I like the idea. It'd be like making a person with driving offences re-sit their road rules knowledge exam, except that for the analogy to work, people started driving without having to pass a knowledge exam in the first place.

Comment: I think that in order to solve the problem, it might be helpful to have some more insight of the steps in between "new user arrives on SO and asks a question" and "new user is automatically question banned and can only attempt to get out of it by asking a new question every 6 months". Because surely such a severe penalty isn't just instantly handed out, out of the blue? Wouldn't the first step be a warning and the next step 1-2 weeks suspension, something like that? I personally have no clue of how this system works.

Comment: @Lundin the users need to have a track record of bad questions and then they get a warning when they try to post a new one. That *should* happen when they are on the verge of a question ban. Afterwards, a question ban is automatically handed out. That's how it works in general. I think it's possible (but sort of hard) to be banned without seeing the warning if the past question track record suddenly gets very bad. Also, there was a bug at one point where the warning wasn't shown.

Comment: @VLAZ Yeah and it would be helpful for them to get a list of all bad questions, including deleted ones, counting towards the ban. As it usually goes, they post on meta asking why they got banned, then some moderator digs up a list of all bad, deleted questions, which is a big waste of moderator time.

Comment: @Lundin The workflow you describe (post on Meta and get a reply from a mod with links) is how it used to work, but that has since been fixed. Users can now see all of their deleted posts by going to "[deleted questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/deleted-questions/current)" and "[deleted answers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/deleted-answers/current)" pages. Links to these pages are at the bottom of the [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=questions) and [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=answers) tabs, respectively, in the user profile.

Comment: @CodyGray Yes I know but they can't actually tell which ones that affected the question ban. Lets say that you for example have a deleted question score 0, voted +1 -1. Should you try to fix that or is it just a waste of time since it is deleted anyway. Things like that.

Comment: No one can tell which specific questions are affecting the question ban, not even moderators. The question-ban algorithm is intentionally undocumented and completely opaque, in order to reduce attempts to game it. The help that does exist, including the Help Center page and the Meta FAQ, are all pretty clear about focusing on downvoted questions, as they're the ones that are probably weighing someone down most heavily. A large number of zero-score deleted questions are also not good. This is clear, too: "Edit all of your questions, paying special attention to those that score 0 or less." @lun

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're talking about two separate things here:

- Users that ask poor questions that get into a question ban
- Users who participate in the review queues

Getting a q-ban is a function of not changing behavior around the questions being asked, such as:

- Questions which are off-topic for the site (covered by the Help Center)
- Disregarding the warning signs that a user gets from the site itself (issued in advance of a user reaching a q-ban level; they may be rate limited first)
- Not engaging on Meta [in good faith] to try and establish what they aren't doing right - this one is forgivable in that people may not know that Meta isn't just a mean and scary place

Seeing how people ask questions on the site is...yes, well, that's one way to improve.  But by the time one gets that far, it's often too late.  You can consider yourself one of the very, very rare exceptions in that you are one of the very few people who [are both impacted by and actually manage to escape q-bans](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/313641/1079354).

This also directly interferes with the motivation of coming to a Q&A site as well - people want to ask questions, not learn about *how* to ask questions *in just the right way* to appease us.  In the last ten years, their position and demeanor on how they approach questions hasn't changed, and I don't see that magically shifting with a new queue.

So I don't think this'd be a great idea; you're just giving people more work that gets in the way of them "just getting their question answered".  It's better to just cut that off at the pass; the warnings that one gets is plenty, and the asker has to dig themselves out of that hole.  It's not *impossible* - you did it, after all - but it's intentionally skewed to be hard because hand-holding people when it comes to question asking is not scalable.

Comment: I would dare to guess that the majority (not everyone!) of those ending up with a question ban didn't just do so because they failed to adhere to various SO rules, but because they failed at basic human-to-human communication. Like "I have a problem, x is not working, how can I solve it [no details provided]". Crap like that is very common. And teaching basic communication skills is not the responsibility or purpose of SO.

Comment: Like for example, seconds after I posted that comment, this question appeared on the main site: "String validation, accepting only strings and space with while loop. If any number is include, it should keep asking to put strings. I have searched on internet but it's hard to find." Sic - that is the _entire_ question body, nothing else. We can't and shouldn't be "saving" these kind of people. We are not their parents.

Comment: I hate the "gloom and doom" attitude here: "They haven't changed. They won't change.  Any proposals that suggest improvements based on a good faith assumption on the asker's part is a bad idea that's doomed to fail". There's always a solution to a problem. Brute forcing different ideas is one way to approach a problem. But, Meta has almost been consistent in "We've known and tried it all. Nothing works. It's not our fault. We won't try to change the status quo any longer.". There is extraordinary resistance against any ideas(especially from new users) threatening the status quo.

Comment: @TheMaster:  I don't see how this is either doom or gloom.  Not to be facetious, but I'm approaching this from the perspective of, well, someone asks a question on Stack Overflow because they're curious about something, and that usually - *usually* - means that they cut out the pesky middleman of meeting our bar of standards, and get angsty when we take moderation action against that.  So, in that light, if I were just a user looking to just get an answer, would I want a queue in my way?  Would it *fix* the problem?  Probably not, which is why I said what I said, how I said it.

Comment: @TheMaster:  But more fundamentally, this *would* require company attention, and while I think that'd be a miracle in itself to get a developer to do something like this, the impact or lasting effect this has is dubious at best, given that the OP is using a sample size of themselves to prove that people *can* learn to improve their questions.  Yes, I've seen it before, and I know that it can be done, but to be blunt, most people just want their question answered.  No sense in trying to find a middle ground with that crowd, in my experience.